# Azure multi branch pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cicd

How do we create multi branch pipeline in azure.
Say there are 4 developers committing to the same branch, for each commit there should be a seperate build pipeline with unit tests.

Comment: Shouldn't those be different branches?

Answer (score 0):

> for each commit there should be a seperate build pipeline with unit tests.

If you want to have a **seperate** build pipeline with unit tests for each commit, you need to create multi pipeline for each branch:

[image]

And if just want to one build pipeline for those multi branch, you may need to have create multi branch triggers:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a CI pipeline. So lets say, there is a main/master branch, 4 developers have pulled this main branch in their PC/laptop. And all 4 of them are about to work on 4 different defects/bugs say bug1,Bug2, Bug3 and Bug4

Each one of them are supposed to create a branch from main. Say bug/Bug1, bug/Bug2, bug/Bug3 and bug/Bug4. So now we got 4 branches.

What you can do now is switch on pull request branch policies in main branch. Please see below screenshot

[image]

Once you switch on this pull request policy, no code can be merged in your main branch without creating a pull request.

Now second part, you have to create a pipeline that will for example, build the code and run some tests.

Now part three: In the same branch policies page, if you scroll down a bit, you will see a setting for "Build Validation" as shown below

[image]

What you have to do here is

Press that + sign and configure the pipeline that you have created earlier here.

What this means is

When say Dev 1 whose branch is bug/Bug1 will raise a pull request to merge in main branch, this Build validation will trigger the pipeline that you have configured here.
So when all 4 Devs will raise 4 pull requests, based on their code changes, this pipeline will get triggered and validate those code changes for build + tests.
Also, based on the code review, if there are any further code changes pushed into these branches (bug/Bug1 etc.), you can configure this Build validation in such a way that this pipeline will get automatically triggered whenever new code changes are pushed into a branch which is connected to a pull request.